# Magento 2.2.4 : Getting 500 Internal Server Error on setup/install

Tags: magento2

I am using Wamp. Am trying to install Magento 2.2.4(Latest Version) on my local machine. But **Getting 500 Internal Server Error**. I have downloaded as a **.zip** format with no sample data. Tried to see any logs, but there is no log folder created under /var folder.

[image]

Added lines in **rootfolder/index.php** to show error on frontend.
[image]

Comment: check permission

Comment: But, am trying to install on my local machine(Windows). Do I have to check any .htaccess file?

Comment: Did you enable error reporting on ?

Comment: @Pawan: Do you mean "the second image which I attached"?

Comment: please check apache error log.

Comment: I got rid of the .htaccess on localhost, was presented with the setup screen of magento 2 for installation.

Answer (score 3):

Same error for me also, I have solved it by enabling the `mod_version` module in apache

To enable it go to `http.conf` in the `conf folder` and find a line that has mod_version in it.

Remove "#" from the beginning to uncomment it.

Then restart apache.

Comment: Good one, fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks SKP,
I had the same problem, I was also getting **500 Internal Server Error** and after uncommenting below line in http.conf file


`LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so`


line, I can start magneto installation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable php errors on index.php

write these two line in index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and then run the page, it will show if any error exist.

May i know your php version ?

Comment: These are the version details. Apache -2.4.27, PHP-7.0.23

Comment: I have renamed .htaccess file under root folder and pub folder temporarily. But I know this is not a permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

In .htaccess, I found like

---

```
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
     Require all denied 
</IfVersion>
```

---

Which caused the error, since my local Apache version is 2.4.76